# Parse csv with multiple delimiters in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv that has its head (row[0]) separated by spaces, but with the content in the rest of the rows separated by \t (and many cells have multiple spaces). How can I parse this csv?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847146/multiple-delimiters-in-single-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the csv as before(whole content) and then use regex(regular expressions) to keep or divide and categirize the content you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all there are a similar question  to your question that should work for you in [Multiple delimiters in single CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847146/multiple-delimiters-in-single-csv-file)

For your specific case you  just can change the delimiter of the first row  to `\t`

```
import csv
import os

inputFileName = "temp.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"

with open(inputFileName, 'r') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'w') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')

    header = next(r)  # get header
    header = "\t".join(header[0].split())
    # write new header
    w.writerow(header)

    # copy the rest
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

And with this script you create a new csv with only one delimiter.

So next you can open the new csv with the delimiter `"\t"`

```
reader = csv.reader(open(outputFileName, "r"),  delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: Your code gave me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean.py", line 8, in <module>
    header = next(r)  # get header
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: It looks like you use python3, this solution works ok for python 2.7, I need to fix that for python3,   in  any case you should specify  in yours tags that you use python3

Comment: this is one solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/28974410/2399444

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr I edited my question and now it works in python 2 and 3

Comment: I use `open(inputFileName, 'rb')` that works in python2 but  not en python 3
so I changed to    `open(inputFileName, 'r')` now works ok in both