# Removing duplicates when all values in .csv file row are identical with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates, row

I am dealing with highly unstructured .csv report and I'm struggling with drop_duplicates function. My dataset's shape is 4084 rows and 39 columns.

My task is fairly simple: I want to use drop_duplicates so that it deletes every row that has all 39 column values identical, but nothing else.

I have tried the following block of code, where new file without duplicates would be saved as "crm_pre_eidup", but I simply get TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable".

```
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader
crm_preprocessed = "CRM_kaikki_data_Pekka1.csv"
crm_pre_eidup = "CRM_kaikki_data_eidup.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep="\t or ,", engine='python')

# Notes:
# - the `subset=None` means that every column is used 
#    to determine if two rows are different; to change that specify
#    the columns as an array
# - the `inplace=True` means that the data structure is changed and
#   the duplicate rows are gone  
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)

# Write the results to a different file
#df=pd.DataFrame(list(reader(crm_pre_eidup)))
df.to_csv(crm_pre_eidup)
df.head()
```

I am quite sure, that solution lies simply in using:
`DataFrame.drop_duplicates(self, subset: Union[Hashable, Sequence[Hashable], NoneType] = None, keep: Union[str, bool] = 'first', inplace: bool = False, ignore_index: bool = False)`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with following changes

- multiple seperator needs to be added with | since it expects a regex
  expression when longer then 1
- filename = crm_preprocessed
- dedup uses all columns by default so you can drop that argument
- make sure your working folder is set correctly or specify the full path

'''

```
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader

crm_preprocessed = "CRM_kaikki_data_Pekka1.csv"
crm_pre_eidup = "CRM_kaikki_data_eidup.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(crm_preprocessed , sep='\t|,', engine='python')

# Notes:
# - the `subset=None` means that every column is used 
#    to determine if two rows are different; to change that specify
#    the columns as an array
# - the `inplace=True` means that the data structure is changed and
#   the duplicate rows are gone  
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# Write the results to a different file
#df=pd.DataFrame(list(reader(crm_pre_eidup)))
df.to_csv(crm_pre_eidup)
df.head()
```

reference: [Multiple delimiters in single CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847146/multiple-delimiters-in-single-csv-file) and
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: ParserError: Expected 40 fields in line 2893, saw 188. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used. Got this

Comment: If you know the qoutes type just add it to the regex: `sep='("\t")|(",")'` for " as quotes