# How to Convert csv to json with separate by '|'

Tags: python

I have csv below

```
id,name,style
1,ma,Exp|Nar|Arg
2,bi,EXp
3,El,rg|Exp
```

Code is below

```
import csv
import json

json_data = [json.dumps(d) for d in csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))]
```

My out

```
['{"id": "1", "name": "ma", "style": "Exp|Nar|Arg"}',
 '{"id": "2", "name": "bi", "style": "EXp"}',
 '{"id": "3", "name": "El", "style": "rg|Exp"}']
```

I need output as

```
['{"id": "1", "name": "ma", "style": ["Exp","Nar","Arg"}',
 '{"id": "2", "name": "bi", "style": ["EXp"]}',
 '{"id": "3", "name": "El", "style": ["rg","Exp"]}']
```

in Expected out **style** has to be in list format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `|` with `,` and wrap `row["style"]` in `[]` before serializing the object to a JSON formatted string.

```
import csv
import json

json_data = []
with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        row["style"] = [row["style"].replace('|', ',')]
        json_data.append(row)

json_data = [json.dumps(d) for d in json_data]

print(json_data)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    '{"id": "1", "name": "ma", "style": ["Exp,Nar,Arg"]}',
    '{"id": "2", "name": "bi", "style": ["EXp"]}',
    '{"id": "3", "name": "El", "style": ["rg,Exp"]}',
]
```

Comment: can you answer like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847146/multiple-delimiters-in-single-csv-file using regex

Comment: some one gave you -1, i dont know why, upvoting and accepting the answer

Comment: @Nons why do you want a regex-based answer? Do you have multiple delimiters?

Comment: no, i just need to apply regex on the particular delimiter

Comment: If you only have `|` delimiter then you really don't need regex.

Comment: okay, still can u update your answer

Comment: @Nons `row["style"] = [','.join(re.split(r'\|', row["style"]))]`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a step for processing you CSV data. The simplest way may be to replace `|` with `,` using `String.replace()`, built-in function. You can also extract the style part and make an equivalent string with something like this:

```py
data = """id,name,style
1,ma,Exp|Nar|Arg
2,bi,EXp
3,El,rg|Exp
"""
for line in data.splitlines()[1:]:
    style = line.split(',')[-1]
    style = f'[{style.replace("|", ",")}]'
```

It reads each line beginning from the second one (first one is just titles), and since style is the last part you can extract it using `String.split()` and its index `-1`.