# Remove lines with all hyphens in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

There is no way I can replace the hyphen (`-`) with a semicolon (`;`) in CSV file with many other formatting.
When I try, I always run into error: `ValueError: i/o operation on closed file.` or `Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`.

`input.csv`:

```
empty line
empty line
empty line
empty line
empty line
------------------------------------
empty line
empty line
empty line
cars,Date,Daypart,'000 (avg),Share (excluded: Other))
car1,2022-01-01,02:00-02:00,24.459,4.3
car1,2022-01-01,02:01-02:01,20.967,3.7
car1,2022-01-01,02:02-02:02,20.967,3.8
car1,2022-01-01,02:03-02:03,13.029,2.3
car1,2022-01-01,02:04-02:04,13.029,2.3
car1,2022-01-01,02:05-02:05,10.621,1.9
car1,2022-01-01,02:06-02:06,10.621,2.0
car1,2022-01-01,02:07-02:07,10.621,2.0
car1,2022-01-01,02:08-02:08,10.621,2.0
```

Python code:

```
import csv

lines = list()
rownumbers_to_remove = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

with open('input.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-16") as read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=",")
    for row_number, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        if row_number not in rownumbers_to_remove:
            lines.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as write_file:
    writer = csv.writer(write_file, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8'])
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

I tried to look for previous solutions, but none of them worked.

EDIT:

I tried to split it at:

```
lines = list()
lines_ = lines.split('-')
```

error message:

```
lines_ = lines.split('-')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Or I tried replace it:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as write_file:
    writer = csv.writer(write_file, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8'])
    for row in read_file:
        lines = row.replace("-", ";")
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

error message:

```
 for row in read_file:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

So actually I don't know how to solve this and where to use `split()` / `replace()` method.

EDIT 2:

I'll try to summarize what I want:

I would like to edit the input file with the following changes:

1. I want to delete/remove the first 10 rows because they contain no data
2. I want to add a new header
3. I want to change the separator from comma (,) to a semicolon (;)
4. I want to change hyphen (-) to a semicolon (;)
5. I want to convert from utf-16 to utf-8
6. I want to create a new file, keeping the old one.

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and post the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry for my late answer, it was sleep time here. I change the question, I hope it helps. Thank you

Comment: Your requirements are rather unclear. Your first sentence talks about replacing hyphens with semicolons, but the code you wrote looks like you want to discard invalid lines at the beginning of the file. I've written an answer which assumes the latter was your real intent; but then maybe [edit] the question further to remove the red herrings.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your time, please check "EDIT 2" in my question, I hope that make this clear.

Comment: Erm, so should hyphen count as a field separator, too; or should fields with a literal hyphen be quoted so that the new semicolon does not count as a delimiter?

Comment: But really, this is definitely too broad. Again, focus on one question per question

Comment: @tripleee yes, hyphen count as a field separator too, but is there any way to handle 2 separator? I made all the changes in my first code, only I couldn't replace the hyphen or use it as a secondary separator.

Comment: Gaaaaah. I suggest you (accept the answer you got, and) ask a new question specifically about that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847146/multiple-delimiters-in-single-csv-file

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, yes, I saw that solution, but I couldn't apply it in the csv module, but I see you added to your answer, thank you

Comment: `for row in read_file` That line is after the `with` block that opens `read_file`, so yes of course that file isn't open any more.  The entire point of a `with` block is that the file is closed when the block ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to split an empty list, not the collection of lines. Surely, you should be able to see that

```
lines = list()
lines_ = lines.split('-')
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
lines_ = list().split('-')
```

which makes no sense at all, and obviously produces the error you got; you can `.split` a string which contains hyphens (so `"foo-bar-baz".split('-')` produces the list `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`), but this isn't a string at all.

(If lists *did* have a `split` method, presumably it would require you to split on a list member which you have to match completely; so perhaps `['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].split('bar')` could make sense, theoretically, but `.split('ba')` would do nothing, because there is no list element which is equal to `'ba'`. But anyway, lists don't have this method, so let's not proceed down this path any further.)

Somewhat similarly, the second error message is clear and obvious; you are trying to loop over `read_lines`, but this is a closed file handle which you can no longer read from. It was closed when you got out of the first `with` context, which implicitly calls `.close()` at the end on whatever you called `open(...) as` on at the beginning.

Anyway, the fundamental problem is easy to solve if we can assume that the lines you want to discard don't contain any delimiter characters. Just read and discard until you see rows with more than one field:

```
with open('input.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-16"
        ) as read_file, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8"
        ) as write_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(write_file, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8'])
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 1:
            continue
        # Replace dash with semicolon in all values
        newrow = [field.replace('-', ';') for field in row] writer.writerow(newrow)
```

It should be easy to see how to adapt this to your `enumerate()` approach if you really want to hard-code a list of line numbers.

In some more detail,

```
        if len(row) == 1:
            continue
```

will discard the current row if it does not contain a comma, by way of skipping the rest of the loop for this row; i.e. not doing the `writerow` to the output.

If you also wanted to remove or replace the header line, you could add a separate condition for that, or (perhaps better) articulate a new criterion which matches all the lines you want to exclude, such as, the last field is not a valid `float` value:

```
        try:
            _ = float(row[-1])
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

To reiterate, this would *replace* the `if len(...):` snippet.

(This also changes the format from comma-delimited to semicolon-delimited, and change the encoding from UTF-16 to UTF-8. Your question does not reveal whether this is an actual requirement or a mistake; I assumed you had included this change consciously.)

Any hyphens are replaced by literal semicolons. So, a value like

```
car,foo-bar,baz
```

gets changed into

```
car;"foo;bar";baz
```

where the second column contains a literal semicolon between `foo` and `bar` (the quotes mark it as not a delimiter).

This also improves speed and robustness by not collecting all the lines into memory. Instead, we read, possibly write, and forget one row at a time.

---

Tangentially, this is not a very focused question. I can understand that there is a specific problem that you are trying to solve; but focusing on the actual *code* problem would make a better question. As such, "why can't I read from a file handle after the `with open` block" and "how do I remove elements at specific positions from a list" are both almost certainly covered multiple times by existing questions. But this is what we mean by asking you to reduce your problem statement to a [minimum reproducible example.](/help/mcve)